Pandas how to groupby close values with large range
I have dataframes for which I want to group relatively close values of a column.
I tried using percentile but often there are huge differences between values in a group.
I.E. column has 1000 values like below
Values
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
5
...
200
...
30000
...
500000

Problem arises when percentile80 of data is 200, but percentil90 is 10000
I tried using diff gt cumsum to group them by a static value but the results do not always work out well for all datasets for when 90% of the values are very close but the remaining 10% is much much larger and spread out.
Edit:
Created a small sample, this is what percentile looks like.
Percentile   Value
    0.10      4.00
    0.20     10.00
    0.30     34.00
    0.40     57.60
    0.50     91.00
    0.60    106.00
    0.70    158.80
    0.80    205.60
    0.90   9114.00

If I split this into 10 groups then the 9th and 10th group will contain values with more than acceptable differences.
This is what it looks like using
.diff().gt(100).cumsum()
values  groups
2       0
2       0
2       0
2       0
2       0
2       0
2       0
2       0
4       0
4       0
4       0
4       0
4       0
4       0
4       0
4       0
6       0
6       0
8       0
8       0
8       0
10      0
10      0
10      0
10      0
10      0
16      0
16      0
16      0
24      0
26      0
28      0
30      0
30      0
30      0
34      0
34      0
34      0
36      0
40      0
42      0
42      0
42      0
48      0
50      0
50      0
52      0
52      0
56      0
60      0
60      0
62      0
64      0
68      0
74      0
78      0
80      0
88      0
88      0
88      0
88      0
94      0
94      0
96      0
96      0
98      0
100     0
100     0
102     0
102     0
102     0
106     0
106     0
106     0
106     0
118     0
120     0
120     0
120     0
128     0
132     0
134     0
136     0
142     0
156     0
160     0
160     0
164     0
172     0
176     0
178     0
180     0
188     0
198     0
200     0
202     0
204     0
206     0
226     0
236     0
276     0
292     0
294     0
324     0
344     0
562     1
808     2
2626    3
3210    4
9770    5
12398   6
13300   7
15756   8
16000   9
16000   9
20000   10
20784   11
23500   12
32000   13
32000   13
42014   14
346046  15

In this case group 0 should be split up more, groups 6-9 can be merged, groups 10-12 can be merged.
Ideally no value of a group should be bigger than 2x any other value of the group.

So you want to do something like an exponential or geometric percentile, yeah? (I don't know if those terms make sense, but that's what came to mind.)

I think we are thinking of the same thing.  Some kind of exponential or clustered percentiles/groups where it'll be like 0-20,21-40,41-80......1281-2560....
The dataframe I am working also have varying ranges.  One could be between  1-1,000, some can be 3,000-30,000,000.
So the number would have to be dynamic.
Ideally if I could set it so the maximum of a group is 2x the min of the group.

OK, so I think your first step in making the groups should be taking the log2, but I'm not sure where to go from there off the top of my head. df['values'].pipe(np.log2). If you can work this into a solution, by all means post an answer :)

For the next step I tried .pipe(pd.cut, 10), which is closer, but doesn't do "no bigger than 2x" like you wanted

"Ideally no value of a group should be bigger than 2x any other value of the group." how would you group [10, 15, 22, 33, 50, 75, 200, 300, 450, 1000]?

I worked it out in a similar way to what @wjandrea suggested.  It's not elegant but works for my purpose.  I simply created another column as the group number by taking log2(value) rounded down, with a minimum of 4.  This way everything under 32 is one group, then doubling each time.

@David Post an answer! :)
